# Google Cloud Run communication between internal services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have 2 cloud run services:

- https://calculator-api.a.run.app  (Ingress: Allow all traffic, Authentication: allUsers)
- https://add-api.a.run.app (Ingress: internal, Authentication: CloudIAM)

The idea is that `calculator-api` is public and it's going to make requests to `add-api`. For some reason, I am getting a 403 when the `add-api` ingress is `internal` but if I change the ingress to to `Allow all traffic`, it works perfectly.

I am getting the IdToken correctly using the following code and then I just inject the token in the header `Authorization: Bearer IdToken`. My receiver `add-api` has permission of `calculator-api` with `Cloud Run Invoker` role.

```
GET request "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://add-api.a.run.app"

Header: {"Metadata-Flavor", "Google"}
```

So, I believe the problem is not the authentication but some kind of network limitation when the ingress is set to `internal`.

Comment: May I know if both services are on the same VPC network? Have you configured a Serverless VPC connector on your service? Please see this doc https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress#internal-services

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) in the same region as your calculator-api service and to [add it to your calculator-api service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) and to set the [egress value to `all`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#egress)

The constraint for now is: the 2 services must be in the same project (or you need to perform VPC peering to achieve this)

Comment: Adding a Serverless VPC to my network worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @MarcoTalento - What hostnames did you use to communicate between your services?  How did they discover eachother?

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi I have used the custom domains that Cloud Run generates. At this moment GCP does not allow using a custom domain between services.

Comment: Great!  Did this configuration cause you any issues with the Cloud SQL connector?