# What are the steps to take when the first Cloud Run service A wants to call API-methods of a second one B with authentication requirement?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I have two Google Cloud Run services A and B running and tested.

The first one is public (i.e. allows unauthenticated invocations) - ...until I find out how to give access to only one app (on web and mobile) - but this is a different topic ;)

The second one is set to "Require authentication".

My question is: How can Cloud Run service A call Cloud Run service B ?

Here my steps so far:

1. I created `Service Account A` for the Cloud Run service A inside IAM, giving "Cloud Run Invoker" permission (roles/run.invoker)
2. I created `Service Account B` for the Cloud Run service B inside IAM, also giving it "Cloud Run Invoker permission (roles/run.invoker).
3. I added `Cloud Run Service Agent` permission inside IAM to Cloud Run B (with the Service Account A email as principal)

--> now I was hoping that I can somehow give Cloud Run service A an Auth-header (for example OIDC token as Cloud Scheduler can set it). But I can't find anywhere on the `Edit & Deploy New Revision` console an appropriate place to set this Auth-header.

The only place I found was a seperate TAB called `SECURITY` that actually allows to set a Service Accout.

BUT UNFORTUNATELY IT ONLY ALLOWS TO SET ONE SERVICE ACCOUNT.

(and the one is already taken by my need for firestore in my project).

[image]

Is there another way to add more Service Account to this Cloud Run A ? If yes, how ?  Or is it all necessary ?

What do I have to do exactly (step-by-step explanation) to be able to call Cloud-Run-service-B-API-methods from Cloud Run service A (knowing that B requires IAM-Authentication) ???

Comment: There is no cloud setting to automatically add authorization to HTTP requests. You must create (fetch) the OIDC identity token yourself via code and add the Authorization header to the HTTP requests. The SDKs have features to make this easier.

Comment: ok, sounds complicated.  What about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341476/google-cloud-run-communication-between-internal-services/66352749#66352749) and the suggestion to use VPC ? (I guess I cannot use it since my Cloud Run A needs to remain public, right ?). Can you give me any hint on how to `(fetch) the OIDC identity token ` ? thank you! or is VPC still an option ?

Comment: [Is this it ?](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#node.js)

Comment: Yes, that document will help you understand how to generate or fetch a token. However, I recommend that you use an SDK to authorize requests instead unless you are writing directly to the REST API interfaces.

Comment: Cloud Run A indeed only calls GET REST cmd with Cloud-Run-B-URL (and `/someRoute?id=xyz` query). I don't quite understand what you mean by `use an SDK to auth request`. Do you mean some sort of third Cloud Run C ? Or do you mean a library inside Cloud Run A ?  And another question: could this token also be provided by the firebas-admin SDK ? (since I'm using firesbase-admin SDK inside Cloud Run A, this would be really nice. But I guess, Firebase and Cloud Run do not share auth-tokens, or do they. Please clarify on the SDK idea ? Thank you very much John. (I'll look into this further tomorrow)

Comment: I believe [this document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-service-to-service-auth) helps you in finding client libraries

Comment: By SDK I mean use one of Google Cloud's Software Development Kits to write your code instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: Thank you John and Roopa, it works great (with [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-service-to-service-auth) or [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#node.js) documents help). One last question using this method: how long will the idToken be valid (it's nowhere written in the doc) ?? (...and I have to say the extra idToken-fetch makes the whole system slower unfortunately)

Comment: By default, access tokens and ID tokens are valid for 1 hour. for additional information you can check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#refresh)

Comment: @iKK - both links are useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned by @John Hanley,

> There is no cloud setting to automatically add authorization to HTTP requests. You must create (fetch) the OIDC identity token yourself via code and add the Authorization header to the HTTP requests. The SDKs have features to make this easier.

The `OIDC identification` token must be created by you using code, and all `HTTP` requests must include the `Authorization header`.

You can try [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#methods) for different methods to get `OIDC` Token. And for using the client SDK’s, you can check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-service-to-service-aut).

And to answer your question,

> how long will the idToken be valid (it's nowhere written in the doc) ?

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#refresh)

> By default, access tokens and ID tokens are valid for 1 hour. A refresh token is a special token that is used to obtain additional access tokens or ID tokens. When your application first authenticates, it receives an access token or ID token, as well as a refresh token. Later, if the application needs to access resources again, and the previously provided token has expired, it uses the refresh token to request a new token. Refresh tokens are used only for user authentication, such as for Cloud Identity or Google Workspace.